# Ionic 3 Native Plugin Error: Java exception was raised during method invocation

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Ionic native plugins on my app started acting weird lately (it was working fine earlier).Whenever I try to call any method related to plugins (mainly ionic-native-camera-plugin, ionic-native-geolocation-plugin) it catches error in promise which reads `Error: Java exception was raised during method invocation`.

I don't know what went wrong, it was working fine few weeks ago.

PS: I tried removing android platform, tried removing each plugins. None of them worked.

**Ionic Info**

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.6.0 
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4, browser 5.0.4
   Cordova Plugins       : not available

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2 
   NodeJS            : v8.11.3 
   npm               : 5.6.0
   OS                : Windows 10
```

here is the entire error message from camera plugin

```
Error: Java exception was raised during method invocation
    at androidExec (cordova.js:963)
    at Object.cameraExport.getPicture (Camera.js:156)
    at s (vendor.js:1)
    at vendor.js:1
    at vendor.js:1
    at new t (polyfills.js:3)
    at vendor.js:1
    at S (vendor.js:1)
    at vendor.js:1
    at l.<anonymous> (vendor.js:1)
```

I think this issue is more related with cordova.

Comment: @HasiiT Did this issue resolved? Do you have iframe in your APP?

Comment: @hareshhanat Sorry, I couldn't resolve this issue (I had to find alternate methods to achieve my requirements). And I did have an iframe in that app. Also, there was extensive usage of native plugins. What do you think about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which helped me was removing the  from HTML and adding it using the scripts (after cordova.js was loaded and deviceready was fired) with simple jQuery call:

```
$('body').append('<iframe id="framed" style="border: none;" src="..."></iframe>');
```

After doing this, I tested on some devices and I was not getting this error anymore.